# Fetching Lastrow from the table in toad

Tags: oracle

I have to fetch the first and last row of the table in Toad.
I have used the following query

```
select * from grade_master where rownum=(select max(rownum) from grade_master)
select * from grade_master where rownum=1
```

The second query works to fetch the first row. but the first not working. Anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you defining a row as first or last? A row can be first or based on some ordering ascending, descending or hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle the data is not ordered until you specify the order in you sql statement.

So when you do:

```
 select * from grade_master
```

oracle will give the rows in anyway it want wants.

OTOH if you do

```
 select * from grade_master order by id desc
```

Then oracle will give the rows back ordered by id descending.

So to get the last row you could do this:

```
 select *
    from (select * from grade_master order by id desc)
   where rownum = 1
```

The rownum is determined BEFORE the "order by" clause is assessed, so what this query is doing is ordering the rows descending (the inside query)  and then giving this ordered set to the outer query.   The outer gets the first row of the set then returns it.

Answer (score 1):

Such request makes sense if you specify sort order of the results - there are no such things in database as "first" and "last" rows if sort order is not specified.

```
SQL> with t as (
  2  select 'X' a, 1 b from dual union all
  3  select 'C' , 2  from dual union all
  4  select 'A' a, 3 b from dual
  5  )
  6  select a, b, decode(rn, 1, 'First','Last')
  7  from (
  8  select a, b, row_number() over(order by a) rn,
  9  count(*) over() cn
 10  from t
 11  )
 12  where rn in (1, cn)
 13  order by rn
 14  /

A          B DECOD                                                              
- ---------- -----                                                              
A          3 First                                                              
X          1 Last
```